# foreach not reached the first time but the second yes

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, foreach

My foreach is not reached the first time I launch the code, but the second time I do (refresh or launch again code), the foreach works for the new DB entry + the olds one . I'm using CodeIgniter.

Code:

```
$visa = $this->db->get('visa');

            echo 'blop2';

            foreach ($visa->result() as $row_card_accept){

            echo 'blop3';


            $cardaccept = $row_card_accept->CARD_ACCEPT;
            $first = substr($cardaccept,6,1);
            $second = substr($cardaccept,7,1);

            if($first == '1' && $second == '1'){
                $this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `CARD_ACCEPT`="B"');
            }elseif($first == '1' && $second == '0'){
                $this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `CARD_ACCEPT`="V"');
            }elseif($second == '1' && $first == '0'){
                $this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `CARD_ACCEPT`="P"');
            }
        }
```

So, blop2 is printed the first time I launch the code, blop3 not. The second time blop3 is printed too and my DB is updated correctly. Why this doesn't work the first time?

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors?

Comment: @TomWright nothing, it's all blank exept "blop2"

Comment: are you calling `$this->db->where()` before you execute this code? That would definitely be a place to look for trouble.

Comment: also, instead of 'blop2', try `echo $this->db->_error_message()`

Comment: @Jerry i'm doing this before:
$this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `COUNTRY`="France" WHERE `COUNTRY`="FRA"');
$this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `COUNTRY`="Germany" WHERE `COUNTRY`="DEU"');
$this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `OPER_HRS`="A" WHERE `OPER_HRS`="00002400"');
$this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `OPER_HRS`="C" WHERE `OPER_HRS`<>"A"');
$this->db->query('UPDATE `visa` SET `PLUS_ALLIANCE_NO_SURCHARGE_FEE`="N"');

Comment: @Jerry and the error message give me: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_error_message()`

Comment: Ah, that was CodeIgniter 2 advice. CI3 must have a way to get the MySQL error, though. If you look at the state of your database before calling `get('visa')` is there any data in it?

Comment: @Jerry this is `$this->db->error();` and there is no errors :/ For the DB, this is empty before putting datas (I always drop before).